# Online Optimization with long-term cost

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning

I am looking for any well-known method to tackle the following online problem with $T$ iterations.
In each iteration $t\in\{1,2,...,T\}$, a concave objective $f_t(\cdot)$ is revealed (Hence dynamic programming does not work).
$$ \max \ \left(\sum_{t=1}^{T}f_t(x_t)\right) - a\cdot\left[-Q+\sum_{t=1}^{T}x_t \right]^+\\
var. \ {\bf x}=(x_t,\ 1\le t\le T)\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad $$

where $[x]^+=\max\{0,x\}$.

The classic online convex optimization problem only has the first term, i.e., $\sum_{t=1}^{T}f_t(x_t)$. The OGD algorithm can achieve sublinear regret.

In this problem, we have a cost term, i.e., $a\cdot\left[-Q+\sum_{t=1}^{T}x_t \right]^+$,  related to all the variables.
Hence the OGD cannot be directly adopted here.

Any other way to tackle this?

Comment: Are $x_t$ scalars? Otherwise, I do not understand the problem's objective function.

Comment: Yes, $x_t$ is scales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

This problem is equivalent to

$$
\max_X\sum_k^T f_k(x_k) + \mu_j\frac{a}{\sum_k^T x_k-Q}
$$

with $X = (x_1,\cdots,x_T),\ \ X_0 = (0,\cdots, 0)$ and $\mu_j$ a positively decreasing sequence. (SUMT - Fiacco & McCormick)

Another method to tackle this maximization problem is with the Dynamic Programming  formulation

$$
\max_X\sum_k^T f_k(x_k) \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ \sum_k^T x_k\le Q
$$

or equivalently the $T$ stage process

$$
S_1(Q) = f_1(Q)\\
S_k(Q) = \max_{0\le x_k \le Q}\left[f_k(x_k)+S_{k-1}(Q-x_k)\right]
$$

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that the objective $f_t(\cdot)$ is revealed slot by slot within the $T$ iterations, hence it is an online problem. In that case, how does SUMT  work?

Comment: @ZhiyuanWang As you said that in each iteration a new concave function is revealed, this is precisely how the Dynamic Programming process works. Regarding the SUMT technique there are many good references disposables in the net.

Comment: @Cesareo This comment is not related to the question but can you give me a recomendation for book that contain technique for solving online optimization problem ?

Comment: Perhaps in the references listed at the end of this thesis, can be found something of interest. https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/82724